# Blazor MudForm validation function not called for initially not shown MudTextField

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am conditionally showing some fields in a `MudForm` and notice that the validation functions are not being triggered for these not initially shown components.

In the example below I have two `MudTextField` that reside within a `MudForm` - one being shown conditionally based on a checkbox.

The latter `MudTextField` does not trigger the validation function unless it is initially shown. If it is initially shown it stops triggering the validation function after being hidden once.

What is the cause of this behaviour, and how can I properly attach/associate the
conditionally shown `MudTextField` with the containing `MudForm`?

```
@page "/page"

<MudForm
    Model="@Model"
    Validation="@(new Func<object, string, IEnumerable<string>>(ValidateCallback))"
    ValidationDelay="0">
    
    @* Validation function gets called for this component. *@
    <MudTextField Label="Property" @bind-Value="@Model.Property" For="@(() => Model.Property)"></MudTextField>

    @if (_visible)
    {
        // This component does not trigger the validation function.
        <MudTextField Label="Property2" @bind-Value="@Model.Property2" For="@(() => Model.Property2)"></MudTextField>
    }
</MudForm>
<MudCheckBox Label="Show/hide child-component" @bind-Checked="@_visible"></MudCheckBox>

@code {

    class TestModel
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    private TestModel Model { get; } = new();

    private bool _visible; // Even if component is initially shown, hiding it once makes the validation stop..

    IEnumerable<string> ValidateCallback(object obj, string arg)
    {
        return new[] { $"{arg} validation failed!" };
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding a class to a textfield which display `none`?

Comment: That works @CyrilleConMorales but does not answer the question. Also, elements in a list might be added that aren't initially existing.

Comment: It's working for me [mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYmHFkQkIoNVgmoJ). Are you using the latest version of Mudblazor?
Or should the component be validated as soon as it is shown?

Comment: Thank you! I have not updated packages since creating the project using the MudBlazor template - which was version 6.0.13. After update to 6.11.0 this is fixed! Create an official answer @Uerschel and I'll accept this as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me: [Mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYmHFkQkIoNVgmoJ).

Make sure to use the latest Mudblazor version.